# Unable to use a custom icon for a notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I have used the following code to generate a notification which works fine but it's not using the icon that I am supplying, instead it defaults to the ic_launcher icon that comes pre-packaged with any android studio project. I have deleted all the default launcher icons but it still shows the launcher icon in the notification.

How do i fix this?

```
final NotificationCompat.Builder notificationCompat = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(alert.getTitle())
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.notif))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notif)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_SECRET);
```

Comment: Where and how do you use this code?

Comment: I am receiving an FCM and then generating a notification manually through android in the FirebaseMessagingService class that I have extended, I am not using any of firebases' helpers to create the notification.